# Trying to find human names in a file using ntlk

Tags: python, nlp

I'd like to extract human names from a text file. I'm getting a blank line as output for some reason. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
import re
nltk.download('names')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.corpus import names

# Create a list of male and female names from the nltk names corpus
male_names = names.words('male.txt')
female_names = names.words('female.txt')
all_names = set(male_names + female_names)

def flag_people_names(text):
    possible_names = []
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    for word in words:
        # Split the word by ' ', '.' or '_' and check each part
        parts = re.split('[ _.]', word)
        for part in parts:
            if part.lower() in all_names:
                possible_names.append(word)
                break
    return possible_names

# Read text file
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()

# Call function to flag possible names
names = flag_people_names(text)
print(names)
```

Here is the input file called sample.txt

```
James is a really nice guy
Gina is a friend of james.
Gina and james like to play with Andy.
```

I get this as the output:

```
[]
```

I'd like to get James, Gina and Andy.

I'm on a MAC Catalina with python3.8.5.
Any idea what's not working here?

Comment: Is the NLTK names list in lower case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the ".lower()" in "part.lower()" since the NLTK names list is not in all lower but proper capitalization.

Comment: Thank you, that works. It looks like to get the names that are in lower case in my file, I'll need to lower the NLTK names list and put the part.lower() back in.